# split and spanned not support error while zip file extraction in c#

Tags: c#

While Zip file Extraction using ziparchival class in C#. It working fine for few files but files with size more than 1 GB it throwing "Split or spanned archives are not supported." I dont get what it mean. How to resolve it?

Comment: Without a more specific question, including a [mcve] showing exactly what you're doing, it's impossible to answer. But, .zip archives are limited to 4GB in size, and you may be running into a limit on the size of an individual entry which would otherwise only be solvable by writing a "spanned" archive (i.e. one in which the whole archive spans two or more files on disk).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error when you attempt to extract a Zip file that has become corrupt during a copy process.

Comment: Same here. The exception `System.IO.InvalidDataException: Split or spanned archives are not supported.` was thrown after 6 hours while opening a corrupt ~8GB zip file with `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open()`.  

A valid zip file of the same size opens in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) allows you to do this. From their documentation:

> The library supports zip passwords, Unicode, ZIP64, stream input and
>   output, AES encryption, multiple compression levels, self-extracting
>   archives, spanned archives, and more.

Answer (score 0):

With Dotnetzip library you can zip even more than 4 gb. Also a lot easer to use then working with filestreams and bytearrays.

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()) {
    zip.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
    zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.Always;
    zip.BufferSize = 65536*8; //buffer size

    foreach (var file in filenames) {
        zip.AddFile(file);
    }
    zip.Save(outpath);
}
```

Comment: Anything out there for .NET Core?